# Dynamic creation of queue in laravel horizon and dispatch job on that queues

Tags: php, laravel

I have a requirement to set queue per user so i want to create queue dynamically (set configuration dynamically) and dispatch jobs on that queue

I want something like i can define queue dynamic at the time of job dispatch.

Please help me for the same.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @SSC thanks for reply, So basically in my project queue is used to send email , Now my requirement is define queue dynamic for particular email domain

Like if email domain is gmail.com then job must be dispatched in queue named gmail, So for this there are to many email domains, So i want to set queue domain as queue dynamically when job is dispatched

Comment: First of all, this question is very broad. However here's something you need to consider: To work with a queue you need a queue worker, however, a queue worker takes as a parameter the queue name (or names) in of the queues it needs to listen on. This happens when the queue worker is launched which ideally is when the application is launched so this is a bit problematic and possibly contradicts the purpose of queues.